# eta-squared outside its 90% confidence intervals?

Tags: r, effect, confidence-interval

I have something in between a statistics and R question.
I ran a repeated-measures ANOVA with the R package ezANOVA. This package automatically provides eta-squared effect sizes. Furthermore, I'd like to report 90% Confidence Intervals and found a great way to calculate these here: http://daniellakens.blogspot.de/2014/06/calculating-confidence-intervals-for.html

However, some of my effect sizes appear to be outside of these confidence intervals, e.g.:

```
F(2, 730) = 20.20, p < .001, eta-squared = .00, 90% CI [.03, .08], 
F(2, 730) = 45.46, p < .001, eta-squared = .05, 90% CI [.08, .15]
```

These are effect sizes of within-subjects factors (see the second way in Laken's blog post).

Here's my question:
Is this statistically possible? And if not, where could be the problem?

Thanks and best,
Mathias

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: thanks although I think I found the solution

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that the ezANOVA calculates the generalized eta squared, while the confidence intervals were calculated for the partial eta squared.